# I am trying to change the placeholder text color of a search controller searchbar textfield

Tags: swift

I am trying to change the color of my searchbar placeholder text in a search controller with NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor but the placeholder text color remains light gray and I can't seem to change it. I have tried many methods such as running the code in view did appear, but can't seem to find the problem.

```
searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.textColor = .black
searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Search", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.black])
searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.leftView?.tintColor = .darkGray
```

Comment: where are you calling this code ? in which method ...

Comment: I am calling this in viewWillAppear

Comment: call it in `viewDidAppear()`

Answer (score 1):

Give a try:

```
@IBOutlet weak var mySearchBar: UISearchBar!

if let textfield = mySearchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField {

    textfield.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    textfield.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: textfield.placeholder ?? "", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.red])

    textfield.textColor = UIColor.green

    if let leftView = textfield.leftView as? UIImageView {
        leftView.image = leftView.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        leftView.tintColor = UIColor.red
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call your method in **viewDidAppear()** when the presentation of the view is done.

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
   super.viewDidAppear()
searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Search", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.white])
}
// and so on
```